# Splitting a column into two groups

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a DataFrame which includes two variables male and female I want to create two new columns that splits up the data into male and female

```
Gender_Years[['male', 'female']] = Gender_Years['sex'].str.split(expand=True)
```

but I get the error `ValueError: Columns must be same length as key`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)?

```
out = (df.pivot_table(index='year', columns='sex', values='Total_Suicides')
         .rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index())
print(out)

# Output
   year  female   male
0  1985   27115  24825
1  1986   27606  32757
2  1987   28454  35529
```

Input dataframe:

```
>>> df
      sex  year  Total_Suicides
0  female  1985           27115
1  female  1986           27606
2  female  1987           28454
3    male  1985           24825
4    male  1986           32757
5    male  1987           35529
```